# Need support for type "MAP" field in CsvToAvro

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro

I am referring below URL to convert CSV to Avro

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/dataflow/transforms/src/main/java/com/example/CsvToAvro.java

my requirement, I have a "map" as a field in my CSV.

{id=1,name=rahul,{address1=Pune,address2=Hyderabad},phone:78888888888}

Now it will fail for {address1=Pune,address2=Hyderabad} this field as it type of MAP.

Anyone, could you please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried using AvroIO? https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check "CsvToAvro.java" implementation it accepts "delimiter" as a parameter.
So if we pass regex like ",(?![^\{]*\}))" a parmeter then it split the CSV string but it will not split inside the braces ({}).